# Loop and Increment date from $_POST variable - PHP

Tags: php, date, variables, for-loop, increment

**RESOLVED in answer below**

Creating a scheduling tool for my users and I am having an issue trying to increment my variable obtained from a dropdown selection:

```
$date_select = $_POST['date_select'];
```

I'm sure it's a textbook fix, but to put it simply...I need to increment $date_select by +1 week for 52 weeks.

I have a dropdown menu starting with the current date, and looping to the end of 365 days, incrementing by 1. No problem here.

```
<select name="date_select" form="create_schedule">
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i <= 365; $i++){
$d=strtotime($i . " Day");
$day = date("n-j-y l", $d) . "<br>";
echo "<option>" . $day . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

This selection is represented by:

```
$date_select = $_POST['date_select'];
```

Next to that, before submitting, users can select a radio button - either M, T, W, Th, F, Sat, or Sun to indicate if they would like to apply their request to that selected day, for every week, for the rest of the year. (Which is what I'm trying to do...which is: increment $date_select by "+1 Week" until the for loop is finished)

This selection is represented by:

```
$repeat = $_POST['repeat'];
```

This is the closest I've gotten...the code below increments for every "Monday" like I want for example...if $repeat == 'M', but the numerical dates are wrong...

```
if(isset($_POST['repeat'])){
        for($i = 0; $i <= 52; $i++){
            $date = strtotime($i . " week", strtotime($date_select));
            echo date("n-j-y l", $date) . "<br/>";  
            }
```

For example: if the date selected is 7-4-16 Monday, the output is this:

11-26-07 Monday

12-3-07 Monday

12-10-07 Monday

12-17-07 Monday

12-24-07 Monday

12-31-07 Monday

1-7-08 Monday

And so forth...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: your `<option>` should have a `value=` attribute. otherwise nothing will get submitted to your form receiving page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED The issue was in the date format..."m-d-Y" is not equivalent to "m/d/Y" when incrementing days weeks or months in regards to how it is output. Somewhere along the lines, "American" date format values and "European" date format values were getting mixed up. I changed the date format within both of the for-loops and got it working.

"Note: Be aware of dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats; if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed. If the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. To avoid potential errors, you should YYYY-MM-DD dates or date_create_from_format() when possible."

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp

Here is the working solution in case anyone is trying to do something similar

```
<select name="date_select" form="create_schedule">
<?php 
for($i = 0; $i <= 365; $i++){
$d=strtotime($i . " Day");
$day = date("m/d/Y l", $d) . "<br>";
echo "<option>" . $day . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>

if(isset($_POST['repeat'])){
  $repeat = $_POST['repeat'];
  echo "<br/>";
        for($i = 0; $i <= 13; $i++){        
            $d=strtotime($i . " week", strtotime($date_select));
            echo date("m/d/Y l", $d) . "<br/>";
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So on PHP you have to classes that can be really helpfull doing that

[\DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) and [\DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php)

So to do what you want I would recommend

```
$firstDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_select));
$baseDate = clone $firstDate;
$intervalToAdd = new \DateInterval('P1w')
if(isset($_POST['repeat'])){
        for($i = 0; $i <= 52; $i++){
            $date [$i] = $baseDate->add($intervalToAdd);
            echo '<option>'.$date[$i]->format('Y-m-d').'</option>';  
            }
```

Comment: Could you gimme the output?

Comment: I figured it out - I put the solution in my original post.

Comment: @Shane it would be better to put the solution in an answer and mark it as correct and answer your own question, then when people in the future view your question it will make more sense  :-)

Comment: I will do that, thank you :) Can't mark it correct for "2 more days" for some reason, but I'll circle back around to it.